# unable to perform time based rolling operations window pandas? Always gives window must be an integer

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

My data is of the form

```
{'transaction': {'merchant': 'merchantA', 'amount': 20, 'time': '2019-02-13T10:00:00.000Z'}}
{'transaction': {'merchant': 'merchantA', 'amount': 90, 'time': '2019-02-13T11:00:00.000Z'}}
.
.
.
```

and I want to perform some rolling operations based upon time. eg the number of transactions that happened in the past 'X' minutes etc.

I have tried multiple ways but can't figure out.
Initially, I gave **len(df.index)** as index. (don't know if it is efficient to do it like that)

Later I also tried giving **data['transaction']['time']** as the index. still, doesn't work.

It always gives the error window must be an integer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = json.loads(line)
        # df1 = pd.DataFrame(data["transaction"], index=[len(df.index)])
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data["transaction"], index=[data['transaction']['time']])
        # df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
        df = df.append(df1)
        ro = df.rolling('2min', on='time').count()
        # ro = pd.get_dummies(df).rolling('2M').count()
        print(ro)
        # df2 = df.merge(ro)

    # print(df2)
    print(df)
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem lies in the specification of `df.rolling()` as it interprets '2min' as a string. Have you tried `ro = df.rolling('2m', on='time').count()`?

Comment: yup. tried it already. 2m 2s etc doesnt works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create list of dictionaries first and pass to `DataFrame` constructor, convert column `time` to datetimes and then use `rolling`:

```
out = [json.loads(line)["transaction"] for line in sys.stdin]
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

And then:

```
df['new'] = df.rolling('2min', on='time')['amount'].count()
print (df)
    merchant  amount                      time  new
0  merchantA      90 2019-02-13 11:00:00+00:00  1.0
1  merchantA      90 2019-02-13 11:00:00+00:00  2.0
```

EDIT:

Your solution should be changed:

```
out = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    data = json.loads(line)
    out.append(data["transaction"])

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['new'] = df.rolling('2min', on='time')['amount'].count()
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(out)`
This will give an error that need index if giving scalar values. 
And I can't use `json.loads(line)["transaction"] for line in sys.stdin`
because the jsons coming from the stream are not necessarily the same. Some dont have **'transaction'** in it at all.
But i will try converting the time column

Comment: @gamer - Yop, I think it is key - converting to datetimes

Comment: I also had that in mind. 
But i tried the example gives the same error
i.e window must be an integer

Comment: I think the index needs to be in the converted DateTime format. Then it might work but im not sure how to do that.

Comment: I can't collect all the data in a list and then do computation as its a streaming app. But I got the idea. just had to change the time format. and apply to_datetime. And it works.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you discuss this as well pls?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285964/how-to-find-duplicate-based-upon-multiple-columns-in-a-rolling-window-in-pandas